# How to kill/handle idle thread in Android (blocked by call to 3rd party app)

Tags: java, android, multithreading

My Android application uses 3rd party library, 1 of methods I used is long-running so I call it from a separate thread.

**Problem**

is that in some circumstances **method which is called from a separate thread hangs** (confirmed bug of that library) and as a result my thread halts.

As far as I know, there are no way to kill thread in Android/Java. The proper way to stop/finish thread is to interrupt threads and to handle "interrupted" exception properly. But as problem is in 3rd party which I don't have control on I end up with having the idle/handing thread.

To workaround the problem, I implemented logic which detect this condition and "bypass" it so my application functions properly. But I'm concerned about my thread which hangs and keeps some resources.

**Questions:**

- Should I be really concerned about the hanging thread?
- Is there any way to kill/wipe that thread?
- Maybe I miss something really simple?

Thanks, any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question answer is yes. Having extra, irrelevant threads can impact other applications (memory use, etc.)

The second answer is no. So you end up with extra, irrelevant threads. (Known as a catch22.)

I manage several multi-threading/tasking frameworks and I do exactly what you have done. It's called expunging a thread. If it doesn't respond and is probably hung forever then the best you can do is ignore it and possibly replace it with a new thread as long as the cycle of expunge/replace does not cause a problem itself. The problem being that the extra threads are negatively impacting other applications.